# The show hide jquery is working fine in the desktop view, but in the phone view the div is overlapping other divs during show()

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

I want to hide and show input text boxes based on selection using select box

The HTML code is:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-1 label2">
                        <label class="control-label m-t-10">List Price: </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <select class="form-control input-filter">
                            <option value="max">Maximum</option>
                            <option value="between">Between</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-1 primary">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Price" class="form-control" id="list_price">
                    </div>
                    <div class="secondary" style="display:none">
                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Min" class="form-control" id="min_price">
                        </div>

                        <div class="and">and</div> 

                        <div class="col-sm-1">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Max" class="form-control" id="max_price">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$('.input-filter').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).val() == "between")                    
    {

        $(this).parent().parent().find(".primary").hide().next(".secondary").show();

    }

    else{
        $(this).parent().parent().find(".primary").show().next(".secondary").hide();
    }

});
```

In the media query want to increase the height of the div during show(); and decrease/go back to normal during hide();

Thanks

Comment: A media query is something else entirely (applying CSS to specific media / screen sizes). What you're asking is very basic, and there are lots of questions on SO already dealing with this topic.

Comment: can you please direct me to one...thanks

Comment: Sure: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+show+hide+divs --- wait, are you asking how to resize a div using jQuery...? Just use `$().css(...);` or `.animate()`. Do some *basic* research first.

Comment: The show hide jquery is working fine in the desktop view, but in the phone view the div is overlapping other divs. I just want to adjust the height of this div so that it does not overlap other divs during show();

Comment: Like epiqueras said use classes to show/hide the divs. Then use CSS and @media queries to set CSS properties for show on desktop vs. show on mobile, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a media query for this. Media queries deal with applying styles depending on screen size. What you could do is add a class to the div and remove it.

```
$('.primary').addClass('hidden resize-prim')
.next('.secondary').removeClass('hidden resize-sec');
```

Include the styles you want to be applied in your stylesheet.

You could also put the classes inside a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .resize-prim {
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

Comment: The show hide jquery is working fine in the desktop view, but in the phone view the div is overlapping other divs. I just want to adjust the height of this div so that it does not overlap other divs during show();

Comment: Then put the applied class inside a media query. I updated the answer.